# why am I getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve a java.lang.NullPointerException for the past hour. This error occurs when I invoke the play() method and input no. I have commented where the error points to down below. I would appreciate some assistance. Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Game
{
private InputReader input ;
private Deck newDeck;
private ArrayList <Card> hand;


public Game(Deck deckToAdd)
{
    input = new InputReader();
    newDeck = deckToAdd;
    hand = new ArrayList <Card>();
}


public void dealCard()
{

    hand.add(newDeck.takeCard());
}

public void showHand()
{
    for(Card showCards: hand){
        if(hand == null){
          System.out.println("(Warning, the deck may have been empty the last time you dealt a      card)");
        }
          System.out.println(showCards.getDescription() + " of " + showCards.getSuit()); 
         //  Error points to above line
    }
}


public int getHandValue()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int handValue = 0;
    while(counter < hand.size()){
        Card checker = hand.get(counter);
        handValue += checker.getValue();
        counter++;
    }
    return handValue;
}

public void play()      //Error occurs when invoking this method and selecing no, points to showHand() method                                 
{
    boolean userWantsToPlay = true;
    while(userWantsToPlay){
        dealCard();
        showHand();
        System.out.println("Hand Value : " + getHandValue());
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (yes or no)");
        String userInput = input.getInput();
        if(userInput == "no"){
            userWantsToPlay = false;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please try to make your examples posted as minimal as possible. This will help us help you to debug the problem.

Comment: Where is `play()` called from?  Can you show that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
if (hand == null) {
   // do your stuff
}
else {
   // do your stuff
}
```

In your case, your second `System.out.println` will be performed always because is not in condition and for both cases(null, not null) will be applied.

**Note:** Also i see in your code more "dirty" code for example you are comparing `Strings` with `==` and it won't work because it compares references, not content. Always when you want to compare `Strings` you need to use `equals()` instead of `==` so

```
userInput.equals("no") {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also replace:

```
userInput == "no"
```

With:

```
userInput.equals("no")
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of your code:

```
for(Card showCards: hand){
        if(hand == null){
          System.out.println("(Warning, the deck may have been empty the last time you dealt a      card)");
        }
          System.out.println(showCards.getDescription() + " of " + showCards.getSuit()); 
         //  Error points to above line
    }
```

should not it be

```
if(hand!=null){
for(Card showCards: hand){
        if(showCards== null){
          System.out.println("(Warning, the deck may have been empty the last time you dealt a      card)");
        }else{
          System.out.println(showCards.getDescription() + " of " + showCards.getSuit()); 

        }
    }
}
```

checking showCards instead of hand.But Debugging would have helped